# How to handle this warning?

Tags: linux, command-line, command, android, hostapd

I try to execute this command I got this warning.

```
root@sabresd_6dq:/system/etc/wifi # hostapd_cli                                
hostapd_cli v2.5-devel-6.0.1
Copyright (c) 2004-2015, Jouni Malinen <j@w1.fi> and contributors

This software may be distributed under the terms of the BSD license.
See README for more details.


Could not connect to hostapd - re-trying
```

How to fix this?

Comment: Make sure that `hostapd` is running.

Answer (score 0):

What does your /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf look like?  Compare it to the following which I know works:

`interface=wlan2
driver=nl80211
ssid=My-Hotspot
hw_mode=g
channel=6
macaddr_acl=0
auth_algs=1
ignore_broadcast_ssid=0
wpa=2
wpa_passphrase=AGoodPassw0rd
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
wpa_pairwise=TKIP
rsn_pairwise=CCMP`

More info on this can be found [here](http://elinux.org/RPI-Wireless-Hotspot).